How to check for manual entry filtering for steps from health connect android
Can anyone please help me how to find or detect programmatically , if user enter's step count manually in google fit and health connect reads the data. how can I check if data entered in health connect was manual or not.
I got Recording Method as 0(Unknown source) for every steps stored in health connect. I have entered manual steps in google fit and health connect synced with steps. then again I have tried for manual check,but got Recording Method as 0(Unknown source).
then calculated hourly data, thought of finding in which hour manual steps added. but no use,
help me if any one worked on identifying manual entry

recordingMethod is optional, so this indicates that Google Fit is not writing the source (even if  you are requesting recordingMethod correctly).

google fit didnt send the steps data to health connect.. currently the issue is till here issue
